# Is there any possibility to set svn property for a certain file with svnadmin setrevprop

Tags: svn

How can I set svn:externals property for a certain revision for certain path in the repository? svnadmin setrevprop seems does not deal with in-repository paths.

I'd like to see the changes in output:
svnlook pg -rRRR /path_to_my_repo/ svn:externals /in_repo_path